# por que não consigo chama uma função pelo input type="submit"?

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tendo o seguinte problema: quando uso o `input type="submit"`, o formulário valida os dados porém não executa a função, já quando uso o `input type="button"`, ele chama normalmente a função.

Por que isso acontece? Estou chamando a função de forma errada? Segue o código

```js
function calcular() {
  var nome = document.getElementById('userName');
  var peso = document.getElementById('peso');
  var altura = document.getElementById('altura');
  var imcAtual = document.getElementById('imcAtual');
  var imcIdeal = document.getElementById('imcIdeal');
  var pesoIdeal = document.getElementById('pesoIdeal');
  var perder = document.getElementById('perder');
  var res = document.getElementById('resultado');

  Number(peso.value);
  Number(altura.value);
  var imcAt = peso.value / ((altura.value / 100) * (altura.value / 100));


  document.getElementById('resultScreen').style.display = 'block';
  var sau = document.getElementById('saudacoes');
  sau.innerHTML = `Hola, ${nome.value}!`;
  imcAtual.innerHTML = `Seu IMC atual é de ${imcAt.toFixed(2)}`;
  if (imcAt < 18.5) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está abaixo do peso';
  } else if (imcAt < 24.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com o peso normal :D';
  } else if (imcAt < 29.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com sobrepeso';
  } else if (imcAt < 34.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com obesidade grau 1';
  } else if (imcAt < 39.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com obesidade grau 2';
  }
  imcIdeal.innerHTML = `O IMC Ideal é entre 18,5 e 24,9`;
}
```

```html
<div id='screen'>

  <form>
    <fieldset id="dados-usuario">
      <input type="text" required name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
      <input type="number" required min="1" max="250" name="peso" id="peso" placeholder="Digite seu peso" />
      <input type="number" required min="1" max="250" name="altura" id="altura" placeholder="digite sua altura sem vírgulas" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Calcular IMC" onclick="calcular()">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div id="resultScreen">
    <p id="saudacoes"></p>
    <p id="imcAtual"></p>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
    <p id="imcIdeal"></p>
    <p>Peso ideal segundo o seu sexo e altura</p>
    <img src="peso.jpg" id="imgPeso">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `submit` serve para submeter o formulário. Se não quer que isso aconteça, não use. Claro que usar `onsubmit` e `preventDefault`, como já indicado, "funciona", mas isso me parece um contorno para um problema que não existiria se vc usasse o tipo correto (no caso, `button`). Então em vez de dar essa volta, prefira usar a coisa certa para cada função. Se não quer submeter o formulário, use o `button`, que como você mesmo já percebeu, funciona corretamente sem precisar de artifícios.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o `button=submit` mesmo. Porém você não poderá chamar a função no botão, pois a função neste cenário é submeter o formulário. Logo intercepte a submissão do formulário com a propriedade "onsubmit".

Exemplo:

```
<form onsubmit="calcular(event)">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Então capture o evento de submissão do form, e previna ele de submeter, e então ele devera apenas chamar a sua função.

```
function calcular(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  /* Restante da sua função */
  return false;
}
```

O `e.preventDefault();` previne que formulário seja submetido (atualização da página). Espero ter sido claro, fique à vontade para perguntar.

Comment: Funcionou, o problema era apenas a falta do e.preventDefault(). Salvou minha vida, estava a 3 dias tendo esse problema :D Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Só complementando a resposta do @fweydson, você pode manter o seu código como está, apenas adicione o código para evitar que o formulário seja submetido como demonstrado na outra resposta, adicionando o `event.preventDefault()` para o evento `onsubmit`:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
```

Veja abaixo o seu código funcionando com o trecho de código acima adicionado ao `form`:

```js
function calcular() {
  var nome = document.getElementById('userName');
  var peso = document.getElementById('peso');
  var altura = document.getElementById('altura');
  var imcAtual = document.getElementById('imcAtual');
  var imcIdeal = document.getElementById('imcIdeal');
  var pesoIdeal = document.getElementById('pesoIdeal');
  var perder = document.getElementById('perder');
  var res = document.getElementById('resultado');

  Number(peso.value);
  Number(altura.value);
  var imcAt = peso.value / ((altura.value / 100) * (altura.value / 100));


  document.getElementById('resultScreen').style.display = 'block';
  var sau = document.getElementById('saudacoes');
  sau.innerHTML = `Hola, ${nome.value}!`;
  imcAtual.innerHTML = `Seu IMC atual é de ${imcAt.toFixed(2)}`;
  if (imcAt < 18.5) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está abaixo do peso';
  } else if (imcAt < 24.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com o peso normal :D';
  } else if (imcAt < 29.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com sobrepeso';
  } else if (imcAt < 34.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com obesidade grau 1';
  } else if (imcAt < 39.9) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você está com obesidade grau 2';
  }
  imcIdeal.innerHTML = `O IMC Ideal é entre 18,5 e 24,9`;
}
```

```html
<div id='screen'>

  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()"> <!-- Adicionado aqui -->
    <fieldset id="dados-usuario">
      <input type="text" required name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
      <input type="number" required min="1" max="250" name="peso" id="peso" placeholder="Digite seu peso" />
      <input type="number" required min="1" max="250" name="altura" id="altura" placeholder="digite sua altura sem vírgulas" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Calcular IMC" onclick="calcular()">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div id="resultScreen">
    <p id="saudacoes"></p>
    <p id="imcAtual"></p>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
    <p id="imcIdeal"></p>
    <p>Peso ideal segundo o seu sexo e altura</p>
    <img src="peso.jpg" id="imgPeso">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, adicionei só o onsubmit mesmo, vocês salvaram minha pele rs valeu!!